# How to add AJAX for the 'Add to Cart' button in wishlist page and in sidebar wishlist product in produst list page in Magento 2.2.3?

Tags: addtocart, ajax, magento2.2.3, wishlist

How to add AJAX for the 'Add to Cart' button in wishlist page and in sidebar wishlist product in product list page in Magento 2.2.3?
Please help.

Comment: You can use this plugin https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/ajax-suite-magento-2/

Comment: i want to add ajax on "add to cart" button in wishlist page , not an "add to wishlist" button